# tags input with typeahead from server local data source

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to synthesize a Json array of objects for the auto complete from server side, and for now I hard coded something like below when page loads but it didn't work. However when I changed it like "local: [{ name: 'Foo' }, { name: 'FFoo' }, { name: 'Ah' }]" in JS file, it works.

Is it possible to render the "local" data from server side and how can I make a Json string using Vb.net?

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    hdTypeahead.Value = "[ { 'name': 'ah'},{ 'name': 'ba'},{ 'name': 'cha'} ]"
End Sub
```

```js
var dataSetBloodhound = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        //local: $('#<%= hdTypeahead.ClientID %>').val()
        local: [{ name: 'Foo' }, { name: 'FFoo' }, { name: 'Ah' }]
    });

    dataSetBloodhound.initialize();

    $('input').tagsinput({
        freeInput: true,
        typeaheadjs: {
            name: 'dataSetBloodhound',
            displayKey: 'name',
            valueKey: 'name',
            source: dataSetBloodhound.ttAdapter()
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/timschlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" />
<input runat="server" id="hdTypeahead" type="text" value="" style="display:none"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
local: JSON.parse($('#<%= hdTypeahead.ClientID %>').val())
```

or please open console log to the same page and get exact value of this element from $('#<%= hdTypeahead.ClientID %>')

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your data coming from server side it is actually parsing of java script array to a variable. Your data is stored in string format in hdTypeahead control's val, so in order to make it an array you have to use some parser present in java script. I have implemented the code as follows:

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="tempApp2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input id="hidTypeAhead" type="hidden" runat="server" />
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var typeAhead = JSON.parse($('#<%= hidTypeAhead.ClientID %>').val());        
        console.log(typeAhead.data);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.vb

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace tempApp2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hidTypeAhead.Value = @"{""data"":[{ ""name"": ""Foo"" }, { ""name"": ""FFoo"" }, { ""name"": ""Ah"" }]}";
        }
    }
}
```

So first understand that you have array data in string not some object while JS have JSON.parse() method which can parse string to JS object. So you simply have to add your array to an object within the string as I have done as follows:

```
hidTypeAhead.Value = @"{""data"":[{ ""name"": ""Foo"" }, { ""name"": ""FFoo"" }, { ""name"": ""Ah"" }]}";
```

I have added my array in data property of the JS object. The next part is to parse it using JSON.parse() the following code will do the needy:

```
var typeAhead = JSON.parse($('#<%= hidTypeAhead.ClientID %>').val());
```

So that's it you will get your array in typeAhead variable's "data" property which you can then assign to your property "local" as

```
local: typeAhead.data
```

Or directly

```
local: JSON.parse($('#<%= hidTypeAhead.ClientID %>').val()).data;
```

Hope it helps